# Trying to do a GET web requisition but ProtocolViolationException was unhandled

Tags: c#, get, httpwebrequest, http-method

I'm trying to do a Web requisition and i cant use POST, because de Web Service is expecting the parameters by GET. But i'm getting a Protocol Violation error on:

```
var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(wReq.GetRequestStream()
```

Can someone help me?

```
WebRequest wReq = HttpWebRequest.Create(InfoBipLogURL);
wReq.Method = "GET";
wReq.Headers["Authorization"] = "Basic " + TokenAutorizacaoInfoBip;
wReq.Headers["Cookie"] = Cookie_Aut;
wReq.ContentType = "application/json";

using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(wReq.GetRequestStream()))
{
    streamWriter.Write(objLog.ToJsonString());
    streamWriter.Flush();
    streamWriter.Close();
}

using (var resposta = wReq.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse)
{
    var streamDados = resposta.GetResponseStream();
    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(streamDados);
    object objResponse = reader.ReadToEnd();
    var retornoLog = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RetornoLog>(objResponse.ToString());
    streamDados.Close();
    resposta.Close();
    return retornoLog;
}
```

Comment: Why can't you use post? It looks to me like you are trying to write data to a url, I would venture that only `POST` / `PUT`  / `DELETE` / `PATCH` allow for writing extra data to the request stream (for `GET` / `HEAD` / `CONNECT` / `TRACE` a body cannot be written), so either don't write to the url, or use a method that allows you to write to the requeststream ;)